# JSPDF pdf content is empty when using html string to be converted

Tags: html, pdf, jspdf

I am using jsPDF to convert an HTML string to PDF page using documentation here, it says "HTML element or string contatining HTML" :

http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#~html

But rendered PDF does not contain anything somehow :

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.html("<html><body style=" +'"background-color:ffffff;"' +"<div align=center><table width=600 border=0 style=background-color:#ffffff><tr><td><table width=120 border=0 align=right>" 
+ "<tr><td width=30></td><td width=10>textetext</td><td width=30></td><td width=10></td><td width=30></td></tr></table></td></tr></div></body></html>", {
 callback: function (doc) {
    doc.save();
}
});
```

What am i doing wrong ? It is wrong usage of jsPDF functions with html string ? I just need to use it to make proof of concept for a requirement if it can be done or not, i know that this is not a good usage of pdf rendering here.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question is not valid anymore, i've changed the library that i have used to create pdf which is more easily maintained on client side which is "pdfmake" (fully text managed by margin management) :

http://pdfmake.org/playground.html

Hope that it could help anybody that visit that page.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, do not forget to accept it.

Comment: I can accept my answer to my own question "tomorrow". SO rules :), but will do it thanks.